# How do I seperate the class's and naming techniques logic?

Tags: c#, oop

This is for an employee calls system.

I have 3 classes so far: Person Manager and Manager team.

Person being the base class, Manager being the class that is able to access permissions to create  new employees using the class ManagerTeam.

For simplicity's sake I am going to skip some of the person class.

```
class Person
{
    private string firstName;
    private string lastName;
    private string phone;

    public string FirstName
    {
        get { return firstName; }
        set { firstName = value; }
    }
}

class Manager : Person
{
    private string Position;

    public Manager() : base()
    {
        Position = "Manager";
    }
    /* 
     * later on maybe some sort of regulation for creating new manager 
     * or new person with acabailities here 
     */
}

class ManagerTeam : Manager
{
    private string Shifts;
    private string On_Call;
    string[] Employee_list = new string[5];

    /*  
     *  maybe this should be turned into a funciton to insert all employees from 
     *  "CreateNewEmployees" into the array. 
     */
    public ManagerTeam() : base() 
    {
        /* 
         * this calls for another object being person to be assigned into 
         * an array for person. 
         */
    }

    static MangerTeam CreateNewEmployee()   /* change this is constructor */
    {
        /* 
         * this assigns shift times and checks if on call and any data 
         * to an employee 
         */
    }
}
```

I am confused because I think of which should be the constructor and which should the function of just loading the objects of new employees into the array of a list of employees, which should be accessed by manager for several reasons later to implemented. Later on the goal is to add employee class and that employee class will have ability to accept and deny Requests, that information will also go into Manager team when it is  developed.

Comment: Think about it abstractly : In your code Manager is iherited from Person and it makes sense as manager is *most likely* a person. However ManagerTeam is not a person and is *not* a manager. It indicates that something is wrong with the architecture here. If I understood correctly Manager team is a team of managers and therefore it shouldn't be inherited from manager class... You might need a collection, for example `List<Manager>` here.

Comment: 1) Is `ManagerTeam` the `Manager` *of* a team? 2) `EmployeeList` should be `List<Person>` or some such, not an array. Arrays have a fixed size, it's extremely rare that they're ever the right thing to use.

Comment: `Manager` has-a `Team`.

Comment: @Fabjan You are write that naming is misleading. I was thinking manager team as in possesive. So like this is the managers team of employees. So its abstraction of manager. Maybe i should rename it "employeeTeam"?

Answer (score 2):

Inheritance in OOP generally implies an "is-a" relationship.  In your case, "is a" `ManagerTeam` a `Manager`? Without knowing the purpose of `ManagerTeam` it's hard to say, but just by the name I would guess no.  So inheritance may not be the right choice in your design.

In terms of constructor versus method, think about what is *required* for a valid object.  If a manger is *required* to have employees to function properly, then that should be in the constructor, otherwise a separate method is appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

The key to any system success is simplification. That is specially true for entity classes which will form the foundation upon which the rest of your application will be built. Get it wrong here and the project most likely will fail or take ages to complete.

Most of the projects I have shared with other developers at work tend to be over-engineered and way more complex than really needed, making maintenance and new improvements difficult.

Regarding your example IMHO you could try with something more simple and increase complexity if / when needed:

Reuse the class Employee for both, normal employees and managers and use the position property to specify the type of Employee.

```
public class Employee
{
    private string firstName;
    private string lastName;
    private string phone;
    //This could be turned into a class or a enum, e.g. Roles for more complex scenarios
    private string position;
    private string team;
    private string shift;

    //You can add a constructor if you want to make sure a position is always provided, but it would be better to handle this at the database level by setting the column as NOT NULL
    public Employee(string position)
    {
         this.position = position;
    }

    ...
}
```

The ManagerTeam class will be the core or helper class that you will use to manage your data including your business rules, it should not contain data of its own and simply call other methods, for example, a database context or unit of work to retrieve data:

```
public static class ManagerTeam
{
     //You need to set this when the user signs in
     internal static Employee CurrentEmployee;

     //This method will return the full list of employees from your data source, you could use an IQueryable instead of the list so you can filter and make queries
     public static IList<Employee> GetEmployees()
     {
          return db.Employees;
     }

     public static IList<Employee> GetEmployeeByPosition(string position)
     {
          return db.Employees.Where(x => x.Position == position);
     }

     public static IList<Employee> GetEmployeesByShift(string shift)
     {
          return db.Employees.Where(x => x.Shift == shift);
     }

     public static IList<Employee> GetEmployeesByTeam(string team)
     {
          return db.Employees.Where(x => x.Team == team);
     }

     public static void CreateEmployee(Employee employee)
     {
           // Only managers can add employees
           if (CurrentEmployee.Position == "Manager") {
               db.Employees.Add(employee);
           }     
     }

     ...

}
```

If you are using a framework such as ASP.NET MVC or WPF or others, you could avoid that class altogether and just handle everything in the controllers, actions, viewmodels, etc...

Comment: thank you for your input. I am going to create employee with a variable for position, that makes much more sense. how do I make sure that the class manager is the only one that has access to "create new employee and to see All employees." I  guess I need two classes and i am having a hard time separating them, one with capabilities to add employees and see a list(manager) and one employee class  for accepting requests, but thats just functions in employee?

Comment: I still also want to make person a class to inherit for employee because I also have class customers that needs to inherit from person, that does not seem to be over-complicating the process right?

Comment: Hi, you can check the role without creating an extra class, check the CreateEmployee method of my last edit, as you can see, you can check the position before executing the database query making sure only managers can do it.

Comment: I would not inherit from person, I would just create a new entity "Customer" even if it contains some of the same fields as "Employee". To me they are different entities, it is not worth it to couple them that way in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a mixin pattern to address this problem. Creating employee is a functionality of an employee who is a manager and manager team is functionality of employees who are managers.
So I would break it out into the following:

```
class Employee
    {
        private string firstName;
        private string lastName;
        private string phone;

        public string FirstName
        {
            get { return firstName; }
            set { firstName = value; }
        }
    }

    interface IManager
    {
        Employee CreateNewEmployee();
    }
    class Manager : IManager
    {
        private readonly Employee _employee;

        public Manager(Employee employee)
        {
            _employee = employee;
        }
        public Employee CreateNewEmployee()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    class ManagerTeam : IManager
    {
        private readonly IEnumerable<IManager> _employees;

        public ManagerTeam(IEnumerable<IManager> employees)
        {
            _employees = employees;
        }
        public Employee CreateNewEmployee()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```